# Convert string (comma separated) to int list in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with a column which contains integers and sometimes a string which contains multiple numbers which are comma separated (like "1234567, 89012345, 65425774").

I want to convert that string to an integer list so it's easier to search for specific numbers.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: raw_input  = "1111111111 666 10069759 9695011 9536391,2261003 9312405 15542804 15956127 8409044 9663061 7104622 3273441 3336156 15542815 15434808 3486259 8469323 7124395 15956159 3319393 15956184
      : 15956217 13035908 3299927"

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x':raw_input.split()})

In [4]: df.head()
Out[4]:
                 x
0       1111111111
1              666
2         10069759
3          9695011
4  9536391,2261003
```

[image: That's how my column looks like]

Comment: please show the dataframe and an expected output

Comment: [int(x) for x in "1234567, 89012345, 65425774".split(,)]

Comment: What is your dataframe? What have tried? What is not working? Add answers to this questions into your question.

Comment: I tried to convert everything into string lists and back to integer list
I also tried to seach for the string directy but I want to be sure its exactly the same number and not just a part like df['ID'].str.contains(value)

Comment: Please do not post images when you could just paste text. We can copy and past from text to reproduce an issue but not from an image. As I am too lazy to re-type a long list of value, I simply never (or scarcely) answer question pasting only images...

Comment: A remark: having in the same column either plain integers or lists of integers is generally a bad design because you will not be able to apply same processing  to those different values. You should think about the future use cases...

Comment: Thats the problem.. I get the data from a "server" and want to convert the values to a format which is better and save it to a sqlite db
So I have no control over the design how the data looks like I'm getting

Comment: @SergeBallesta I can copy the numbers, but not like a list because I only have the data in my database.

Comment: This is a natural consequence of the nature of the data (one or more values), which doesn't naturally fit a tabular format.  In cases like this, it is better to split the column into multple columns, `ID1`, `ID2`, etc.  Add enough columns to deal with the longest case and leave `NA`s where you are missing data.

Comment: @yardsale8 yes I also thought about that but I was optimistic that there is an easy solution...
Thanks I think I will do that..

Comment: You may not have control on the input data, but you have full control on your dataframe structure :-). My advice would be to step back, examine the input data, define what you want to do with it, **from there** design your data structure and then study how you can convert the input data into the expected format. You may have to iterate and try different formats if the conversion step is too complex, but do not blindly load the input into a dataframe (which is a rich and expensive format) without knowing how you will process it.

Comment: FYI, you might want to include code that will allow people to quickly prototype a solution (e.g. see my edit to your question).  This will allow authors to more easily test out a quick solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your column contains strings and integers, you want probably something like this:

```
def to_integers(column_value):
    if not isinstance(column_value, int):
        return [int(v) for v in column_value.split(',')]
    else:
        return column_value

df.loc[:, 'column_name'] = df.loc[:, 'column_name'].apply(to_integers)
```

Comment: Thanks that works and is the answer I was looking for.. still not sure if I will make it like this or change the whole programm from the beginning like in the comments.
But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution to cases like this, where a column has 1 or more values, is splitting the data into multiple columns.

Try something like

```
ids = df.ID.str.split(',', n=1, expand=True)
for i in range(3):
    df['ID' + str(i + 1)] = ids.iloc[, i]
```